# How can I change the order of the RadioGroup widget appears in HelloFormStuff from Android Dev?

Tags: java, android, widget, radio-group

I'm going through the tutorial [HelloFormStuff](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html). I started having problems adding the RadioGroup widget. After moving some brackets around I finally got it to work.

When I tried to add the final (2) widgets, I found if I tried to add them in main.xml below the RadioGroup they wouldn't appear in the app. I guess I could just call it finished and move on, but I took the time to enter all the code (not ctrl C, ctrl P) and damn it, the widgets should show up where I tell them to! Why can't I add widgets below the RadioGroup?

```
public class HelloFormStuff extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
              // Perform action on key press
              Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    final RadioButton radio_red = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);
    final RadioButton radio_blue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_blue);
    radio_red.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
    radio_blue.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    final ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
    togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    final RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
    ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "New Rating: " + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }   
    private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```java
Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this,
  ((RadioButton) v).getText(),
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if it crashes, but I don't see any problem with your code.
Here is the main.xml, everything should show up:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="check it out" />
<RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Red" />
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Blue" />

</RadioGroup>
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Vibrate on"
    android:textOff="Vibrate off"/>
    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is REALLY old, but I just started learning Android and I ran into the same thing. Maybe this will help new-comers I found out that the reason you do not see them is because the value of `layout_height` for the `RadioGroup` should be `wrap_content`. The example says to make it `fill_parent`. But as you may know by now, the object's height will go to the bottom of the screen.

@Duy's main.xml is correct, but I just wanted to point out the exact reason.